# Constraint layout Issue java.lang.AssertionError: TOP

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I started using Constraint Layout, I facing Assertion Error while compiling the design file alone this issue will occur. What is the right way to fix this issue? I mess up with hole day. Here is my XML design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cL_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/card_background">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gL_right_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gL_vertical_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50364965" />
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gL_bottom_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gL_image_size_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgVw_AddClips_recVw_icon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/qik_highlights_shape"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dummy_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_cloud_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gL_image_size_margin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.ibot.cyranoapp.customview.TextViewFont
        android:id="@+id/txtIp_recVw_AddClips_Name_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/recVw_Template_channel"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/fa_preview_button_text_grey"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gL_image_size_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.ibot.cyranoapp.customview.TextViewFont
        android:id="@+id/txtIp_recVw_Components_Name_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/recVw_Template_Components"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/fa_preview_button_text_grey"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gL_image_size_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtIp_recVw_AddClips_Name_title" />

    <com.ibot.cyranoapp.customview.TextViewFont
        android:id="@+id/txtIp_recVw_channel_subscribers_hint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/channel_subscribers"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/fa_preview_button_text_grey"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gL_image_size_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtIp_recVw_Components_Name_title" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rBtn_AddClips_SelectionIcon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:button="@drawable/qik_checkbox"
        android:text="@null"
        android:theme="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gL_bottom_margin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gL_right_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_template_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/fa_preview_button_text_grey"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gL_right_margin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gL_right_margin" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_template_selection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/fa_green_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_template_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And My Error Log here:**

> java.lang.AssertionError: TOP
>           at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.Guideline.getAnchor(Guideline.java:159)
>           at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget.immediateConnect(ConstraintWidget.java:1597)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:1031)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:794)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1542)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:849)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2583)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1893)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7098)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Comment: Ya, the problem is the missing constraints, you can find the solution details from https://stackoverflow.com/q/50188620/6299045

Comment: Possible duplicate of [constraint-layout lib update from 1.0.2 to 1.1.0 got error (Guideline.getAnchor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188620/constraint-layout-lib-update-from-1-0-2-to-1-1-0-got-error-guideline-getanchor)

Comment: [Check this](https://android.jlelse.eu/fixing-constraintlayout-guideline-assertionerror-exception-in-android-5dce450b76fb) for more info.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use a vertical guideline, any view constrained to it should do it horizontally and same thing for horizontal guidelines.

In your case, your are constraining `view_template_1` vertically to a vertical guideline so change this :

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gL_right_margin"
```

by a horizontal guideline

Always check your layouts and make sure you add the proper constraint to a guideline.

Answer (score 6):

I was missing the `android:orientation="horizontal"` /  `android:orientation="vertical"` tag from the `GuideLine`. Make sure you have added it correctly.

Finally, it should look like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cv_rank_status"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cv_rank_status" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove plus symbol from referencing your guidelines. For example here `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gL_image_size_margin"`